# Facebook integration for sending the app invite in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I need to integrate my app with facebook sdk.Now I need to integrate facebook app so that i can send invite to the user on my friend list.Now on sending the invite I need the list of users to whom I have send the invite so that I can keep track of the users to whom I have send invite.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: There can be anyway I can implement it

Comment: Facebook deliberately does not return that info at this point, because then it will be abused by shady apps to reward users for sending out invites, which is not allowed.

Comment: If suppose if I get a particular user's facebookid can then I send the invite to the specific user.